# foreach two different objects with a single cycle

Tags: java, foreach

I have two different objects, but when I do a single for loop they both have the common object.
Since I want to do the only foreach. Why do you give me error in the syntax foreach?

```java
ListResponse rp = sctService.search(usercode, dateFrom, dateTo, amountFrom, amountTo, debit);
CancellableSearchResponse ca = sctService.searchCancellable(usercode, amountFrom, amountTo);


for (Bonifico b : rp.getBonifici();ca.getBonifici()) {
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to foreach on two different lists in Java

Comment: are there other ways?

Comment: look at my answer, those are the only ways

Comment: If you have a library such as _Guava_ or _Apache Commons Collections_ in your dependencies, check out [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101579/foreach-two-different-objects-with-a-single-cycle#comment108097532_61101810). If you don't have such a library you could always implement something similar yourself, if you deem the effort worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop two lists with one foreach in java. If you want to loop them together you can do:

```
int i = 0;
List<Bonifico> rpBonifici = rp.getBonifici();
List<Bonifico> caBonifici = ca.getBonifici();
while (i < rpBonifici.size() || i < caBonifici.size() {
    if (i < rpBonifici.size()) {
        rpBonifici.get(i);// do something with it
    }
    if (i < caBonifici.size()) {
        caBonifici.get(i);// do something with it
    }
    i++;
}
```

If you're 100% sure that the lists have the same size, you can take off the checks before accessing the elements of the list:

```
int i = 0;
List<Bonifico> rpBonifici = rp.getBonifici();
List<Bonifico> caBonifici = ca.getBonifici();
while (i < rpBonifici.size() || i < caBonifici.size() {
    rpBonifici.get(i);// do something with it
    caBonifici.get(i);// do something with it
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Another option is to create an `Iterable` from the combination of the others, then for-each over that one. See [`IterableUtils#chainedIterable(Iterable...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/index.html) and  from _Apache Commons Collections_ and [`Iterables#concat(Iterable...)`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.2-jre/api/docs/) from _Guava_ for examples.